# How to get a php document to show a result based on a if statement of a javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Inside some HTML code from my PHP document I've the following line:

```
Current Year <span="year"></span>
```

And then the following JS code to show our current year.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var m = new Date().getMonth();
var y = new Date().getFullYear();
if (m<2) {
    document.getElementById("year").textContent = y-1;
}
else {
document.getElementById("year").textContent = y;
}
</script>
```

So, "IF" our current month is one of the first quarter (Jan, Feb, March) the code was intended to show "2013" (our current year -1) in the element with id "year". "ELSE" the code was intended to show "2014" in same element.

I tried to remove the IF statment and use only

```
document.write(y);
```

what resulted in our current year as expected.

Then I also tried to change document.getElementById for document.write as follows:

```
Current Year <script type="text/javascript">
    var m = new Date().getMonth();
    var y = new Date().getFullYear();
    var x = "";
    if (m<2) { x = y-1 }
    else { x = y }
    document.write(x);
```

Without any lucky...

Comment: Instead of just saying that it didn't work, it would be helpful if you explained what _did_ happen. Did you get no output? Did you get unexpected output? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<span="year"></span>
```

to

```
<span id="year"></span>
```

...and `m < 4` because it's April (just for testing)...

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielgasser/YNS8V/)

Comment: Damn... first try was the document.write, how it didn't work I used document.getElementById but forget to mention the "id" inside my <span> tnx!

Answer (score 0):

The error is your html code. You have forgot to add **id** to div. Change

```
Current Year <span="year"></span>
```

To

```
Current Year <span id="year"></span>
```